# how to start an eventstore in Gitlab-CI test

Tags: unit-testing, gitlab-ci

I have the following code in my gitlab repo

package.json

```
{ 
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register --watch-extensions ts,tsx \"src/**/*.{spec,test}.{ts,tsx}\""
  }
  ...
}
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  image: node:8
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
```

test.ts

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const Exec = promisify(exec);
describe(test, async () => {
  before(async () => {
    // next line doesn't work in GitLab-CI
    await Exec(`docker run -d --rm -p 1113:1113 -p 2113:2113 eventstore/eventstore`);
    // an so on
  })
});
```

it work well when I run "npm run test" in my local machine.

My Question is how can I run this test in Gitlab-CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to run tests that connect to eventstore docker you can use gitlab services:

> GitLab CI uses the services keyword to define what docker containers
>   should be linked with your base image.

first, you will need to setup [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)

then you will be able to use eventstore as a service. here is an [example with postgres](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html#use-postgresql-with-the-docker-executor). more information [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-to-use-other-images-as-services).

Example:

```
test_server:
    tags:
      - docker
    services:
      - eventstore:latest
    script:
      - npm install && npm run test
```

Edit:

To [access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) the service:

> The default aliases for the service’s hostname are created from its image name

Or use an [alias](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services):

```
services:
- name: mysql:latest
  alias: mysql-1
```

Comment: I using this method all this while but fail to access to eventstore. Then I found out that I can't access the eventstore service using localhost, because the service run at 172.17.0.2. The IP can be obtain from environment variable created by eventstore at 'EVENTSTORE_EVENTSTORE_PORT_1113_TCP_ADDR'

Comment: @simon you can read about how to access the service here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services. I will edit the response